# How to round the corner in a cycle metapost path, when the first/last point is a corner?

Tags: metapost

It is useful to have most simple coordinates, to define picture primitives, such as the "fullcircle" expression.

When I define a 1x1 rectangle

```
prologues:=3;
outputtemplate:="%j-%c.png";
outputformat:="png";
hppp:=.03;
vppp:=.03;

beginfig(1);
pickup pencircle scaled .5;
p=(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
draw p scaled 3;
endfig;
```

and draw it with a thick pen, I get three rounded corners and one sharp corner.

[image: The sharp corner]

Of course I could "overdefine" the path with a mid-point

```
p=(.5,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--(0,0)--cycle;
```

but now `point 0 of p` would be (.5,0). Are there other solutions to get the corners in a cyclic path rounded?

Comment: Interestingly, I obtain the round corner if
I increase the scaling a bit:
`pickup pencircle scaled 0.7;`

Comment: Right. This looks like a bug then... hmm. Actually this is a problem with scaling png. I will close this question and setup a bug report for metpost...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug in the PNG driver of Metapost